# swift smooth (interpolate) between incoming continuous data

Tags: ios, swift, smoothing, real-time-data

Working in Swift I have a function which is called on arrival of new data (Double between 0 and 1). I need this function to go smoothly to the next value. In another language (MaxMSP) I could simply say go in 20 milliseconds from the previous value to the new one, this would even work if new data arrived before the set time was over. How could I achieve this in Swift? I've found vDSP.convolve() but I'd need an array of values to interpolate between, in my case data is real time and I have the latest value and previous value(s). The code I have is

```
var previousValue: Double = 0
var value: Double = 0 {
    didSet {
        valueDidChange()
    }
}
private func valueDidChange() {

    let valueSmooth = value * //smoothing magic with previousValue
}
```

Comment: Take a look at [Kalman Filter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kalman_filter). The simplest filter you can make is `let valueSmooth = k * value + (1-k) * previousValue`, tune `k` between `0` to `1` to get your desire smoothness and responsiveness

Comment: @RickyMo You solved this question, thank you!